# Low performance when inserting large amount of dynamic DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, dynamic

I need to create a flow script which inserts 1000s elements per second in different columns, when amount reaches 30 elements per column I'm deleting them.

I noticed I can use CSS to insert my data, by the sheer number of DOM elements slows down when I have let's say 100 columns and 50 rows in each; and the whole process becomes choppy.

I'm creating the elements and storing in array to also improve the performance.

How to perform this task with better performance in pure JavaScript?

https://jsfiddle.net/r7qpmd4o/4/

```
<script>
    var elems = [],
            buffer = 1000,
        temp_row,
        temp_col,
        temp_var;

     // run
     create();
     clock();

    function clock() {
        setInterval(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            temp_col = document.getElementById('col' + i);

          temp_row = pop();

             if(temp_col.firstChild) {
                temp_col.insertBefore(temp_row, temp_col.firstChild);
            }
            else {
                temp_col.appendChild(temp_row);
            }

            if(temp_col.childNodes.length > 30) {
                temp_col.removeChild(temp_col.childNodes[30]);
            }
        }
      }, 1);
    }

    function pop() {
        if(elems.length < 1) {
            create();
      }

        temp_var = elems[elems.length -1];
      elems.pop();

      return temp_var;
    }

    function create() {
        for(var i = 0; i < buffer; i++) {
        temp_row = document.createElement('div');
        temp_row.className = 'a';

        elems.push(temp_row);
      }

      console.log('Elems created: ' + buffer);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using documentFragment ... but I got lost trying to see if that would be at all advantageous

Comment: What about instead of having one timer, make each column having it's own timer? Would that perform better or worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var elems = [],
        buffer = 1000,
    temp_row,
    temp_col,
    temp_var;

 // run
 create();
 clock();
 var nodeCOunter = 0; //counts what node until 30 hits
function clock() {
    setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp_col = document.getElementById('col' + i);

      temp_row = pop();

         if(temp_col.firstChild) {
            temp_col.insertBefore(temp_row, temp_col.firstChild);
        }
        else {
            temp_col.appendChild(temp_row);
        }

        if(nodeCounter == 30){
           temp_col.removeChild(temp_col.childNodes[30]);
           nodeCounter = 0; //reset
        }
          else
        {
           nodeCounter += 1; 

    }
  }, 1);
}

function pop() {
    if(elems.length < 1) {
        create();
  }

    temp_var = elems[elems.length -1];
  elems.pop();

  return temp_var;
}

function create() {
    for(var i = 0; i < buffer; i++) {
    temp_row = document.createElement('div');
    temp_row.className = 'a';

    elems.push(temp_row);
  }

  console.log('Elems created: ' + buffer);
}
```

Comment: Having own counter should bring some results. Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might try switching out setInterval for requestAnimationFrame and then place the content of your create function at the top of your clock function. The function call is a pretty expensive one.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/GodmXE

JavaScript:

```
var elems = [],
        buffer = 1000,
    temp_row,
    temp_col,
    temp_var;

 // run
 //create();
 clock();

function clock() {

  //formally part of the create
  //function
  for(var i = 0; i < buffer; i++) {
    temp_row = document.createElement('div');
    temp_row.className = 'a';

    elems.push(temp_row);
  }

  console.log('Elems created: ' + buffer);
  //end create function

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp_col = document.getElementById('col' + i);

      temp_row = pop();

         if(temp_col.firstChild) {
            temp_col.insertBefore(temp_row, temp_col.firstChild);
        }
        else {
            temp_col.appendChild(temp_row);
        }

        if(temp_col.childNodes.length > 30) {
            temp_col.removeChild(temp_col.childNodes[30]);
        }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(clock);
  });
}

function pop() {
    if(elems.length < 1) {
        create();
  }

    temp_var = elems[elems.length -1];
  elems.pop();

  return temp_var;
}

function create() {

}
```

Comment: Your code generated 1000 more rows every function call. That definitely won't help the performance. Also, what is the benefit of the request frame function? I never used one.

Comment: I apologize, I was thinking the goal was to create more rows per second. The requestAnimationFrame is generally faster than setInterval. I was going to post a jsperf example to but the site was having some issues when I tried it.  I will it give another shot later.

Comment: I will have to also take note of that. never used it before. Thanks.